# Javascript: Remove original and duplicate character from string

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I need is the remove both original character and its duplicates regardless if its lowercase or uppercase. also it should retain if its uppercase or lowercase

Here is my current code but it can't filter if the string is uppercase then lowercase.

```
const removeDuplicateChar = s => s
  .split('')
  .filter( ( cur, index, self ) => self.lastIndexOf( cur ) === self.indexOf( cur ) )
  .join('')
```

> Actual Output

```
'services' becomes 'rvic'
'stress' becomes 'tre'
'ServicEs' becomes 'ServicEs'
'streSs' becomes 'treS'
'DeadSea' becomes 'DdS'
```

> Expected Output

```
'services' should be 'rvic'
'stress' should be 'tre'
'ServicEs' should also be 'rvic'
'streSs' should also be 'tre'
'DeadSea' becomes 'S'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be faster, as there's no `indexOf` inside a loop:

```js
const removeDuplicateChar = s => {
  let counts = Array.from(s.toLowerCase()).reduce(
    (counts, char) => counts.set(char, (counts.get(char) || 0) + 1) && counts,
    new Map());
  return Array.from(s).filter(letter =>
    counts.get(letter.toLowerCase()) == 1
  ).join('');
}

['services', 'stress', 'ServicEs', 'streSs', 'DeadSea'].forEach(word =>
  console.log(word, removeDuplicateChar(word))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

### The magic of  `.toLowerCase`

You just need to use `.toLowerCase` whenever you deal with checking, but not before because you'll permanently alter the result to all lowerCase, which is not what you want.

```
const toLowerCase = string => string.toLowerCase
removeDuplicateChar = s => s
  .split('')
  .filter((cur, index, self) => self.map(toLowerCase).lastIndexOf(cur.toLowerCase()) === self.map(toLowerCase).indexOf(cur.toLowerCase()))
```

Granted, this is the messy edition, but it keeps your code so you don't have to change much.

Comment: yeah this works great. thanks man. however I might still need a more readable code if possible :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
var str = "DeadSea";
var s = str.toLowerCase();
var arr = s.split("");
arr.forEach(a => {
    if (arr.indexOf(a) !== arr.lastIndexOf(a)) {
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(a, "gi"), "");
    }
});
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Nice use of regex :D

Answer (score 1):

**Answer as why your code doesn't give the expected output:**

`indexOf()` compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator).

Which makes `indexOf()`  *case sensitive*.

**The solution:**

You need to normalize the case of both strings before you do `indexOf`

You can make a methods like this:

```
function indexOfCaseInsenstive(a, b) {
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();

  return a.indexOf(b);
}

function lastIndexOfCaseInsenstive(a, b) {
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();

  return a.lastIndexOf(b);
}
```

Or use `toLowerCase()` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a lower case string and use lower case letters to find.

```js
function unique(s) {
    var l = s.toLowerCase();
    return Array
        .from(s, c => l.indexOf(c.toLowerCase()) === l.lastIndexOf(c.toLowerCase()) ? c: '')
        .join('');
}

console.log(['services', 'stress', 'ServicEs', 'streSs', 'DeadSea'].map(unique));
```

Comment: genius as usual

Comment: @SalmanA, stings are immutable, so no it does not change the original string.

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry i wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the `lastIndexOf` and `indexOf` of the character's instance and use `s` as reference so that, you won't need to use `self` and join it to be a string again.

```
const filterDuplicateCharacters = s => s
  .split('')
  .filter((c) => s.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(c.toLowerCase()) === 
             s.toLowerCase().indexOf(c.toLowerCase()))
  .join('')
```

Comment: Nice reuse of the variable from the initial param to make it compact and readable at the same time

Comment: Just for the sake of brevity, this function is quite slow. It computes `s.toLowerCase()` twice for all elements in `s`, an overhead which could be easily reduced by caching this unchanging value beforehand.